# Using Navigation craches the app. How do I use Navigation and NavHost with Compose to handle screen changes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning how to use `Jetpack Compose` in Android.
I followed the Codelab from [https://developer.android.com/](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation?hl=en#0) and tried to adapt it in my app.

The app now craches at launch with a FATAL EXCEPTION in the `NavHost` component with the following error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: com.ishim.playmusic, PID: 22673
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
    at com.ishim.playmusic.compose_layout.NavigationGraphKt$PlayMusicNavGraph$1.invoke(NavigationGraph.kt:132)
    at com.ishim.playmusic.compose_layout.NavigationGraphKt$PlayMusicNavGraph$1.invoke(NavigationGraph.kt:64)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:392)
    at com.ishim.playmusic.compose_layout.NavigationGraphKt.PlayMusicNavGraph(NavigationGraph.kt:64) 
    at com.ishim.playmusic.compose_layout.MyThemeKt$ScaffoldBarsGeneric$4.invoke(MyTheme.kt:212)
    at com.ishim.playmusic.compose_layout.MyThemeKt$ScaffoldBarsGeneric$4.invoke(MyTheme.kt:188)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
...
```

Here's the `Composable` function in which the error occur:

```
@Composable
fun PlayMusicNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    currentlyPlayingState: CurrentlyPlayingState,
    musicDB: MusicDB
) {
    Log.d(TAG, "PlayMusicNavGraph -- What's happening")
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = SongListView.route,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "PlayMusicNavGraph -- composable BEGIN")
        composable(
            route = SongListView.route,
            arguments = SongListView.arguments,
            deepLinks = SongListView.deepLinks
        ) {navBackStackEntry ->
            Log.d(TAG, "PlayMusicNavGraph -- composable $route")
            val tracklist = navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getString(SongListView.trackListArg)
            TrackList(
                list = musicDB.songs,
                padding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
                onClickSong = { songID ->
                    navController.navigateToPlayingView(songID) }
            )
        }

        composable(
            route = AlbumListView.route,
            arguments = AlbumListView.arguments,
            deepLinks = AlbumListView.deepLinks
        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            Log.d(TAG, "PlayMusicNavGraph -- composable $route")
            AlbumCardGrid(
                list = musicDB.albums,
                paddingValues = PaddingValues(8.dp),
                onClickAlbum = { navController.navigateToTrackList(SongListView.route)}
            )
        }

        composable(
            route = ArtistListView.route,
            arguments = ArtistListView.arguments,
            deepLinks = ArtistListView.deepLinks
        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            Log.d(TAG, "PlayMusicNavGraph -- composable $route")
            ArtistsGridView(
                list = musicDB.artists,
                padding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
                onClickArtist = { navController.navigateToTrackList(SongListView.route) }
            )
        }

        composable(
            route = PlaylistView.route,
            arguments = PlaylistView.arguments,
            deepLinks = PlaylistView.deepLinks
        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            Log.d(TAG, "PlayMusicNavGraph -- composable $route")
            PlaylistCardList(
                list = listOf(),
                padding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
                onClickPlaylist = { navController.navigateToTrackList(SongListView.route)}
            )
        }

        composable(
            route = PlayingView.routeWithArgs,
            arguments = PlayingView.arguments,
            deepLinks = PlayingView.deepLinks
        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            Log.d(TAG, "PlayMusicNavGraph -- composable $route")
            val songID = navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getLong(PlayingView.currentlyPlayingArg)
            val song = MusicDB.getTracks(LocalContext.current, songdId = songID)

            PlayingView(
                song = song[0],
                currentlyPlaying = currentlyPlayingState.currentlyPlaying)
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "PlayMusicNavGraph -- composable Is it done?")
}
```

I added the screen to the manifest as intents and verified that the correct dependencies where in the `build.gradle`.
The screen changes worked before I swiched from using `intents` to cusing `Navigation`

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example which demonstrates the usage of the `Navigation` best practices. You can follow this.

Here is the demo which also includes the `BottomNavigation`.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsetsSides
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.only
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.safeDrawing
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.windowInsetsPadding
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Settings
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.CenterAlignedTopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBar
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBarItem
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.res.vectorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination.Companion.hierarchy
import androidx.navigation.NavGraph.Companion.findStartDestination
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

@Composable
fun Ex11(
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = NavRoute.Home.route,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        composable(route = NavRoute.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen() {
                navController.navigate(it)
            }
        }
        composable(route = NavRoute.Settings.route) {
            SettingsScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SettingsScreen() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Settings Screen", fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navigateTo: (route: String) -> Unit
) {

    val topLevelDestinations = listOf(
        TopLevelDestination(
            route = NavRoute.Screen1.route,
            selectedIcon = R.drawable.home,
            unselectedIcon = R.drawable.home_outline,
            iconText = "One"
        ), TopLevelDestination(
            route = NavRoute.Screen2.route,
            selectedIcon = R.drawable.bulb,
            unselectedIcon = R.drawable.bulb_outline,
            iconText = "Generate"
        ), TopLevelDestination(
            route = NavRoute.Screen3.route,
            selectedIcon = R.drawable.my_files,
            unselectedIcon = R.drawable.my_files_outline,
            iconText = "My Files"
        )
    )

    val showBottomBar = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val title = remember {
        mutableStateOf("Home")
    }
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(title = {
                Text(
                    text = title.value,
                    color = Color.White,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                )
            }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
            ), actions = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Settings,
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    contentDescription = "Settings",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            navigateTo(NavRoute.Settings.route)
                        }
                        .padding(8.dp)
                )
            })
        },
        bottomBar = {
            if (showBottomBar.value) {
                HomeBottomBar(destinations = topLevelDestinations,
                    currentDestination = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.destination,
                    onNavigateToDestination = {
                        title.value = when (it) {
                            "sc1" -> "Screen 1"
                            "sc2" -> "Screen 2"
                            else -> {
                                "Screen 3"
                            }
                        }
                        navController.navigate(it) {
                            popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                            restoreState = true
                            launchSingleTop = true
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(it)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            HomeNavHost(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .weight(1f),
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = NavRoute.Screen1.route,
                navigateTo = navigateTo
            )

        }
    }

}


@Composable
fun HomeNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: String,
    navigateTo: (route: String) -> Unit
) {

    NavHost(
        navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination, modifier = modifier
    ) {

        composable(route = NavRoute.Screen1.route) {
            Screen1()
        }
        composable(route = NavRoute.Screen2.route) {
            Screen2()
        }
        composable(route = NavRoute.Screen3.route) {
            Screen3()
        }


    }
}


@Composable
fun Screen1() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "One Screen", fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen2() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Two Screen", fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen3() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Three Screen", fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}


@Composable
private fun HomeBottomBar(
    destinations: List<TopLevelDestination>,
    currentDestination: NavDestination?,
    onNavigateToDestination: (route: String) -> Unit
) {

        NavigationBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .windowInsetsPadding(
                    WindowInsets.safeDrawing.only(WindowInsetsSides.Horizontal + WindowInsetsSides.Bottom)
                )
                .height(70.dp),
        ) {
            destinations.forEach { destination ->
                val selected =
                    currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == destination.route } == true
                NavigationBarItem(
                    selected = selected,
                    onClick = { onNavigateToDestination(destination.route) },
                    icon = {
                        val icon = if (selected) {
                            destination.selectedIcon
                        } else {
                            destination.unselectedIcon
                        }
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(icon),
                            modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp),
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text(
                            text = destination.iconText
                        )
                    })
            }
        }
}
```